# Show an element is in the orthogonal complement of a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a linear subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. I want to show that if $$
||x-y|| \ge ||x||, \quad \text{for all} \ y \in M,
$$
then $x\in M^\perp$.

Let $x\in H$ and $y\in M$ such that $||x-y||^2 \ge ||x||^2$. This is equivalent to
$$
||x||^2 - 2(x,y) + ||y||^2 - ||x||^2 \ge 0.
$$
That is
$$
- 2(x,y) + ||y||^2 \ge 0.
$$
As this inequality this has to hold for all $y\in M$ we have that $(x,y)$ must equal to zero. Is this correct or have I missed some details?

Comment: Is $M$ closed subspace of a $H$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses Just a linear subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to better motivate the last step. A possible way to do it is the following. Suppose that $(x,y)\neq0$. If necessary, take $-y$ instead of $y$ so that $(x,y)>0$. Now take
$$\epsilon < \frac{(x,y)}{\|y\|^2}$$
and set $y':=\epsilon y\in M$ to get
$$\|y'\|^2 = \epsilon^2\|y\|^2<\epsilon(x,y)=(x,y')\ ,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't really see what the contradiction is, and how this relates to my last step? I have $-2(x,y) + ||y||^2 > 0$, I don't see how you are using that in your approach?

Comment: @eurocoder I constructed a $y'\in M$ contradicting the assumption...